# How add multiple condition expressions for <ui:output>

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have requirement that need to display section title back ground color based on multiple conditional expression

for example i have account name as section header so i want to display section header back ground color Red if there is any open opportunities are available or  Green if account status active  else nothing

```
style = "{!v.Custom_object__c.Account___r.Total_Open_Opportunities__c > 0 ?'rgb(135, 5, 0)':''}"
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: no i dint get any error,  am not aware of logic to apply it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very much doable.

Since you haven't given any specific information about how you are holding the list of opportunity, I am assuming you have a list of opportunity in `aura:attribute` named `oppList`. And Account is stored in acc aura:attribute.

You need the following ternary operator in your style attribute of div. You can have nested operators as well like this.

```
<div style="{!v.oppList.length > 0 ? 'background:red;': (v.acc.isActive ? 'background:green;' : '')}">
...
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you it is working fine,  i have tried in another way using '||' condition